# Searching in easyui filter removes selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I enabled filter in easyui datagrid with multiple row selection and checkbox.

When I do a search after selection some rows in the grid, that clears all my previous selection.

Same way, when I filter some rows and select few rows, clearing the filter text will clear the selection.

Jsfiddle is here:

```
dg.datagrid('enableFilter', [{
    field:'listprice',
    type:'numberbox',
    options:{precision:1},
    op:['equal','notequal','less','greater']
}])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xz955jLe/170/

Comment: Try adding idField: 'itemid' to your datagrid properties.

Comment: That didnt solve the problem

Comment: I've edited ypu fiddle. It works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/xz955jLe/173/

Comment: great. works. post write this as answer, this may help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add idField : 'itemid' to your grid properties.

```
I've edited your fiddle. It works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/xz955jLe/173
```